# How to extend extjs DirectStore's api??? Besides CRUD I want to add new methods

Tags: api, extjs, crud

I'm quite a newbie at extjs. I've been searching for this for quite long but haven't found an answer. How to extend DirectStore's api? I want to add new methods besides CRUD.

For example, now the store looks like:

```
var dirStore = new Ext.data.DirectStore({
...
api: {
            create: ...,
            read: ...,
            update: ...,
            destroy: ...
        }
```

Now I want to add a new method called *newMethod*, the store will look like:

```
var dirStore = new Ext.data.DirectStore({
...
api: {
            create: ...,
            read: ...,
            update: ...,
            destroy: ...,
            newMethod: ...
        }
```

How can I make *newMethod* work?? Thanks for any help!! I've been driven crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

What type of method are you looking to add to the CRUD api?

You are probably best off invoking the method (whatever you'd put on the righthand side of newMethod: ) directly.